# How to make div visible and not visible

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to make div visible & not visible after clicking button in MVC3.

Answer (score 4):

You could also check the status of the div, whether is hidden or visible, and use the same button to show or hide it. In addition, you can change the caption of the button accordingly:

```
        $('#button1').click(function() {
            if ($('#id1').is(':hidden')) {
                $('#id1').show();
                $('#button1').val('hide');
            } else {
                $('#id1').hide();
                $('#button1').val('show');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Visible/Invisible and at the same time removing the space that the element occupies in the page

```
$('#someid').toggle(); // to toggle between visible/invisible
```

or `$('#someid').show();` and `$('#someid').hide();`

If you want to make visible/invisible but maintain the space the element occupies then use `$('#someid').css({visibility:'hidden'});` and `$('#someid').css({visibility:'visible'});`

---

But the most correct way in both cases is to create a css class and add that class or remove it from the element

**CSS rule**

```
.hidden{ display:none; }
```

and use `$('#someid').addClass('hidden')` and `$('#someid').removeClass('hidden')`

Comment: I like the CSS method as well, note you can also use `$(selector).toggleClass("hidden");`

Answer (score 2):

Asp.net-MVC uses jQuery be default, so this is the jQuery version:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
     $('#divId').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better do it in client side with Javasctipt

```
//to hide element
document.getElementById("MyElement").style.display = "none";
//to show element
document.getElementById("MyElement").style.display = "inline";
// where MyElement is id of your div
```

Comment: Why is it better to do it in pure javascript? Chances are the jquery framework is already being included in the page so you might as well utilize it as it can also handle any cross-browser issues that may crop up.